# StackPanel margin issue

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When I set a `Margin` from the *Top* to `15` for the `TextBox`:

```
x.Margin = new Thickness(100, 15, 0, 0);
```

This works fine and everything it ok, but then I want to make a `ComboBox` also appear `15px` from the top - it doesn't work.

```
y.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);
```

This is the code for the button I click to create the ComboBox and the TextBox:

```
int t = 0;
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        TextBox x = new TextBox();
        x.Name = "Title" + t;
        x.Text = "Title...";
        x.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
        x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        x.Height = 25;
        x.Width = 200;
        x.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        x.Margin = new Thickness(100, 15, 0, 0);
        spStandard.Children.Add(x);


        ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
        y.Name = "Combo" + t;
        y.Text = (t + 1).ToString();
        y.Height = 25;
        y.Width = 45;
        y.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        y.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);
        spStandard.Children.Add(y);

        t++;
}
```

Here is a picture of what happens when I run the application - it shows where the ComboBox gets put:

[image: Controls displayed by my program]

Comment: The `TextBox` has also "margin left" set to 100, what is the desired result ?

Comment: @NovitchiS I want the ComboBox to appear next to the TextBox on the left hand side, but its not putting it on the same line. The MarginLeft is just moving the TextBox to the left so I can fit the ComboBox in.

Comment: I don't get the problem do you wan't them to be aligned vertically ?

Comment: @AndriiKalytiiuk Yes, it is set to 100 to move the text box up, but it shouldn't matter that the horizontal alignment is, its the vertical alignment that that I need to be the same so its on the same line?

Comment: @eranotzap Yes, on the same line.

Comment: If you use a `Vertical` `StackPanel` all it's children will be arranged Vertically, don't expect them to be on the same line. Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then why are you moving your TextBox's 100 units  right ?
move the comboBox

Comment: @NovitchiS Is there any way around the issue?

Comment: @eranotzap So the combobox will fit on the same line but its not going on the same line.

Comment: o never mind , now i get what @NovitchiS said never mind this can't be done using a Stack panel , create a grid with 2 columns and as many lines as your cb / txtbx pairs .

Comment: alternatively you can stack each pair horizontally in a stackpanel and add these stackpanels to the main vertical stackpanel

Comment: @eranotzap I think the answer below is what you mean, this doesn't work.

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.** Jeez, how many times do I need to repeat myself?

Comment: I would highly recommend reading [WPF Layouts - A Quick Visual Start](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30904/WPF-Layouts-A-Visual-Quick-Start), and making sure you are selecting the correct layout control for your items. It sounds like you want a `WrapPanel` or a `UniformGrid` with 2 columns instead of a `StackPanel`, because a `StackPanel` is made to stack all the controls placed in it, either horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem, you shouldn't create controls in code behind but it will get the job done:

```
int t = 0;
private void btnAddTitle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //a new stackpanel is used to arrange items Horizontally for each line
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };

    TextBox x = new TextBox();
    x.Name = "Title" + t;
    x.Text = "Title...";
    x.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
    x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
    x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
    x.Height = 25;
    x.Width = 200;
    x.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);

    ComboBox y = new ComboBox();
    y.Name = "Combo" + t;
    y.Text = (t + 1).ToString();
    y.Height = 25;
    y.Width = 45;
    y.Margin = new Thickness(0, 15, 0, 0);

    sp.Children.Add(y);
    sp.Children.Add(x);        

    spStandard.Children.Add(sp);

    t++;
}
```

Comment: The `{ Orientation = Horizontal };` bit doesn't exist.